# Flashplayer and LiveMocha

Tags: flash

Prior to the most recent update, I have been able to use LiveMocha with FlashPlayer.
Now FlashPlayer is unrecognized by LiveMocha.  I get the "Get Flash" message.
How do I fix this?

Comment: Could you please tell us what browser are you using (e.g. Firefox, Google Chrome or Chromium) and what version (usually in Help > About menu or chrome://chrome/ for Chrome)? Also, make sure you have either `adobe-flashplugin`, or `flashplugin-installer` package installed.

Comment: I would really, really love to be able to use LiveMocha with Firefox :( Nonetheless, the Chrome solution can save the day.

Answer (score 2):

I did this steps and been able to use FlashPalayer in LiveMocha. This lines install the Google Chrome stable, that comes with FlashPlayer 11.4.

1. Run `wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -`.
2. `gksu gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list` (opens a graphical text editor)
3. Paste the text: `deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main`
4. Run `sudo apt-get update`.
5. Run `sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable`.

Answer (score 2):

I recently ran into this problem and none of the workarounds using chrome worked. The latest version of flash for ubuntu is simply too outdated. I ended up installing the windows version of firefox using Wine so that I could install the latest version of flash. That worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Livemocha's website is basically hostile to Linux in general. If you try to login to Livemocha today (18 August 2013 - maybe they will fix it), using either Firefox or Google Chrome, their site will not let you login or create an account if you are using Linux.

I have to say that up to now I have never encountered a webpage (even on microsoft.com) that is quite as hostile to Linux as this. I am a long-time Livemocha user, and even paid for an account there (which I now regret), but I think it's time to move to one of the alternative language-learning sites.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I figured that livemocha requires flash version 11.3 or higher and somehow my firefox and chromium browser were showing  11.2 in http://www.whatismyflash.com/ . I reinstalled chrome browser and the site worked in chrome browser. I believe reinstalling of browser should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just using the Google Chrome browser worked for me.

(note: this makes sense, since Chrome comes with its own version of flash built in)

Answer (score 0):

```
google-chrome --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.17 Safari/537.36"
```

Use that in terminal to bypass the linux hostility.  However, if you have chromium and not chrome, you are on your own

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, whenever I try to log in it shows me this error message:

```
Livemocha is not supported on Linux.

Visit us from your Mac or PC to access the full Livemocha experience. We can't wait to see you there!
```

[image: Livemocha is not supported on Linux.]

But, when I ran this command on the Terminal, it worked:

```
chromium-browser --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.17 Safari/537.36"
```

Here, it works.

[image]